# How to prove that the given limit doesn't equal 0

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives

I have to prove that 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{r_n\cos^3\phi_n\sin\phi_n}{r_n^4\cos^6\phi_n+\sin^2\phi_n}\ne0
$$
But I don't know how. It seems that the limit should equal $0$ indeed.

P.S. Initial task was to prove that
$$
g(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\frac{x^3y}{x^6+y^2}, (x,y)\ne(0,0)\\
0, (x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}
$$
is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think polar coordinates are not very useful here.

If we try to find derivative along line $x = t$, $y = t^3$ (found s.t. we would have $y^2 = x^6$), we have $g(t, t^3) = \frac{t^6}{t^6 + t^6} = \frac{1}{2}$ - so $g$ isn't even continuous at $(0, 0)$, so it's not differentiable.

Comment: Why isn't $g$ continuous then? Is it because $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}g\ne\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: $g(t,t^3)=1/2$ and $g(t,0)=0$, hence $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}g(x,y)$ does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Fred's comment captures the answer.

The function has the limit $0$ only if that is the limit along **all paths** leading to the proposed limit point $(0,0)$.  If you select a linear path $y=kx$ then the limit as $x\rightarrow0$ does indeed reach $0$ for any $k$.  Also the linear path $x=0$ gives that result.  But you also must consider **nonlinear** paths to $(0,0)$ such as $y=x^3$.  Along that path the function has a constant value but it's $1/2$, not zero.  Try it!

Thereby, all paths do not agree on any one limit and so the limit **does not exist**.